# AttributeError: 'dynamodb.Table' object has no attribute 'primary_key'

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

this is a trivial question but I didn't found the answer on how to get the `primary` from a *dynamoDB table in AWS*.
(I know we can from the `dynamodb` object but I would like to keep it directly from `dynamodb.Table`.

**Problem:** `AttributeError: 'dynamodb.Table' object has no attribute 'primary_key'`

**Solution:** Something like `my_table.get_primary_key()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getmembers(table, lambda a: not (inspect.isroutine(a))))
```

**Result:**

```
[....('attribute_definitions', [{'AttributeName': 'mail', 'AttributeType': 'S'}]), ...]
```

**Answer:**:

```
def get_primary_key(table):
    return table.attribute_definitions[0]["'AttributeName"]
```